# How can I create a bookmark to the listing of a computer's network shares?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I have a server on my network which shares a lot of folder where I keep almost all my data. In my Windows enviroment I have a shortcut that goes to "\SERVER" which lists all those folders.

I am looking for the same in Ubuntu. There seems to be a limitation that you can only create shortcuts (or bookmarks) to individual folders, like "\SERVER\Pictures" for example and not to the folder listing.

If I go into a folder, that folder will appear under the Network headline to the left so I can then right click it and choose "Add Bookmark".
The server won't appear there if I just list its shares, therefore I can't save a bookmark.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Usually, navigating to `network:///` lists all available shares.

Comment: "There seems to be a limitation" Please explain what you did *exactly* and what happened instead. Do this by *editing* your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on Browse Network and the double click on the server as it should be listed. Then simply click bookmarks and add from the menu bar

If you cannot access the menu bar press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to create a bookmaker.

[image]

Comment: I only have the File menu, not the others: http://i43.tinypic.com/idzqec.png
I am on the latest Ubuntu btw.

Comment: you can pres Ctrl + D, if you don't have a main bar. It will bookmark the page.

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer to my question, if you rewrite it as an actual answer I will pick it :)

Comment: re-written it :)